# I could not understand this question for practicing python

Tags: python-3.x, fibonacci

Could anyone please help me in understanding the question for this.

I got this from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-nth-multiple-of-a-number-in-fibonacci-series/

Given two integers n and k. Find position the n\’th multiple of K in the Fibonacci series.
Examples:

Input : k = 2, n = 3
Output : 9

3'rd multiple of 2 in Fibonacci Series is 34
which appears at position 9.

Input  : k = 4, n = 5
Output : 30

5'th multiple of 5 in Fibonacci Series is 832040
which appears at position 30.

Comment: What do you not understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are interested in the numbers that are divisible by `k` in the fibonacci sequence. Among these numbers, you seek the index of the `n`th, that is, the index `i` such that the `i`th fibonacci number is divisible by `k`, and such that there are exactly `n-1` fibonacci numbers before that one that are also divisible by `k`.